# How do I emulate Vim's 'softtabstop' in Emacs?

Tags: vim, emacs, indentation

I've been trying to get into emacs lately, and one of the things I need to get right is indentation.

Example 1:

```
sub foo {
    my $bar = 'quux';
    |
```

Example 2:

```
sub foo {
    my $bar = 'quux';       |# foo
```

Imagine that the pipe character in the above examples indicates the cursor position. Now, I use (4) spaces for every indent level (no tabs), and I have emacs setup to indent my code automatically with that in mind. No problems there. But in the examples above, if I were to hit backspace at the indicated cursor positions, I want emacs to backspace all the way back to the next indent level (column / 4). That is, I want it to treat the preceding whitespace as if it were made up of tabs. Instead, it always just erases a single space character.

In vim, I turn on 'expandtab' to make it insert spaces instead of tabs, and 'softtabstop', which makes it (among other things) backspace to the next "soft tabstop" as described above.

In emacs, I suppose I could (if I knew emacs/elisp better) bind backspace to a function which does something like the following:

```
if indent-tabs-mode is nil
    if the cursor position is preceded by whitespace
        calculate the position of the previous "soft tabstop"
        if there's enough whitespace
            backspace all the way to that point
        else
            backspace by one character
```

What I want to know is, is there a simpler way to do this, and/or does anyone know of an existing solution?

Comment: This is complicated by the fact that it looks like you're writing Perl, and cperl-mode (the best Perl mode for Emacs) already binds backspace to `cperl-electric-backspace`.  (Although that function doesn't do anything critical, so you could get by without the behavior it provides.)

Comment: One small update: I got one thing wrong. When vim can't go back to the next soft tab stop, it deletes as much whitespace as possible (i.e. 1 to 3), not just 1.

Comment: Solution updated to delete as much whitespace as possible (up to the tab stop)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me, where the `'tab-width` is used as the width of the columns.  Set the key in the appropriate keymaps...

```
(local-set-key (kbd "DEL") 'backward-delete-whitespace-to-column)
(defun backward-delete-whitespace-to-column ()
  "delete back to the previous column of whitespace, or as much whitespace as possible,
or just one char if that's not possible"
  (interactive)
  (if indent-tabs-mode
      (call-interactively 'backward-delete-char-untabify)
    (let ((movement (% (current-column) tab-width))
          (p (point)))
      (when (= movement 0) (setq movement tab-width))
      (save-match-data
        (if (string-match "\\w*\\(\\s-+\\)$" (buffer-substring-no-properties (- p movement) p))
            (backward-delete-char-untabify (- (match-end 1) (match-beginning 1)))
        (call-interactively 'backward-delete-char-untabify))))))
```

Comment: See: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BackspaceWhitespaceToTabStop (has an *enhanced* version).

Comment: Nice, but found `backward-delete-char-untabify` quite annoying, some users may want to replace it with `backward-delete-char`.